# Отключение запроса

Tags: php, sql, mysql

Здравствуйте. Написал запрос, но при закрытии вкладки с запросом в базу добавляется еще одна пустая строка. Какая функция помогает закрыть sql-запрос при его завершении? Вроде `exit();` или `mysql_close();`, но как ими пользоваться? Или просто функция, с помощью которой в таблицу добавляется только 1 строка.

Код запроса:

```
$insert = mysql_query("INSERT INTO users SET name='".$name."'");
```

Comment: Вы путаете где-то в определениях. Поясните, что вы понимаете под 

>еще один пустой столбец.

___

Просто так строки не добавляются. У вас в коде где-то дублируется запрос.

Comment: Извините, строки. 
Дубликата нету. Только один)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mysql_close закрывает соединение с сервером MySQL.  
Подробнее и с примером http://php.net/manual/ru/function.mysql-close.php  
А вообще стоит сразу показывать и код запроса, возможно, в нем и есть ошибка )

Comment: Добавил код.

Comment: Сложно судить по такому куску ) Скорее всего, как и сказал @ua6xh, у вас дублируется запрос, проверьте, может, где-то выше есть цикл.

Comment: Нету дублирования, я это проверил в первую очередь.

Comment: Форма на простой странице, а сам запрос с модальном окне, не знаю, может быть изза этого или нет. То есть у меня вот так сделано

`<form action="#modal" method="post">
....
</form>`

Comment: @cnofss, может быть, при открытии модального окна и нажатии кнопки "отправить" (я не знаю, как у вас всё устроено, просто догадки) отправляется два Ajax-запроса? Или у вас не Ajax? Очень мало информации. Если Ajax, вы в консоли браузер смотрели, что точно не 2 запроса уходят на сервер? Может быть, в методе контроллера, который обрабатывает ваше событие, где-то вызывается некий другой метод, который вы не заметили? 

To be continued;

Comment: @cnofss, на самом деле, на вашем месте я бы обернул все куски кода, которые работают с базой в какой-либо маломальский набор функций, чтобы вы могли в любой момент времени увидеть все (!) запросы, которые проходят к базе при загрузке страницы, и в данной ситуации это спасло бы вам кучу времени, да и дебажить проще, когда видно всё с первого раза.

Comment: У меня не на AJAX. Просто страница, на ней форма, в которой action="#modal" и в модальном окне который сделан на html, css там php скрипт. Проблема то в том, что отправляет сначала один запрос, а после закрытия модального окна он отрпавляет еще один, но уже пустой. Я думал сделать проверку на водимость, то есть if ($email == null) { } Но я не могу сделать, так как у меня там не одна переменная, а их 14.

Вот тема на счет этого http://hashcode.ru/questions/361159/php-как-сделать-массовую-проверку

Comment: Попробуйте после записи в базу удалять пришедший POST (правда, не знаю, прокатит или нет):    
<pre><code>    
if (isset($_POST['name_but_submit']))    
 {    
   if ((isset($_POST['email'])) and ($_POST['email']!=''))    
    {    
      // обработка переменных    
      ...    
      if (mysql_query("INSERT INTO users SET name='".$name."'"))    
       {    
         // если инсерт прошел, то удаляем пост    
         unset($_POST['email']);    
       }    
    }    
 }    
</code></pre>        
----    
Почему-то не получилось через код вставить.